# get the memory address instead of double value

Tags: c++

I just practice on c++ and want to get the area of circle from a given radius but the result giving me a memory address instead of value

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double a, n, r;
    n = 3.14159;
    cin >> r;
    a = pow(r,r) * n;
    cout << "A=" << a<<endl;

}
```

while the input is 100.64 i got the output

```
A=1.13759e+202
```

Comment: What makes you think that number is a "memory address"?

Comment: That's not a memory address. `1.13759e+202` is *approximately* the value of 3.14159 * (r^r). If you meant to compute a different formula, you'll need to adjust your code -- I assume you want the area of a circle, in which case you either want `r*r` or `pow(r,2)`.

Comment: how can i get the number

Comment: @Mahmoudeldieb: That *is* the number you computed

Comment: @Mahmoudeldieb It *is* a number. `1.13759e+202` is a perfectly-accepted scientific notation format that is far less annoying to write than 11375900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (which, again, is *approximately* the result of evaluating the bizarre formula you expressed in your code)

Comment: Mahmoud, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation. This has nothing to do with memory addresses. It's the "default" output mode for huge numbers, for whatever your output mechanism is.

Comment: If a variable contains the value of `pi`, why not call it `pi`?

Comment: oh i got it thanks for all ;but how to get the 4 numbers after decimal

Answer (score 1):

> but the result giving me a memory address instead of value

> while the input is 100.64 i got the output
>
> ```
> A=1.13759e+202
> ```

Your assumption is wrong. That is not a "memory address". That is the correct result of `π × rʳ`.

However, your calculation is not the correct one for area of a circle. Correct formula is `π × r²`.

Bonus hint: `r * r` is typically better than calling `std::pow`.

Bonus hint 2: C++20 has constant `std::numbers::pi` in the `<numbers>` header. It provides you with the closes representable approximation of π.

Comment: oh i got it thanks a lot  ;but how to get the 4 numbers after decimal

Comment: @Mahmoudeldieb I recommend reading the documentation if iostreams.

Comment: i used this cout.precision(4); but it gives me A=3.182e+04

Comment: @Mahmoudeldieb Precision means the number of ***all*** digits, not only those after the decimal point.